# Error al compilar proyecto Android con Xamarin - Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2015, xamarin

Al crear un proyecto Android con la API19 (4.4.2) en Visual Studio 2015, cuando quiero iniciar la aplicacion me aparecen estos errores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Error N1 :**
"aapt.exe" salió con el código **-1073741819**. APP_Activity_Sync   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets   1665

**Error N2 :**
El archivo "**obj\Debug\android\bin\packaged_resources**" no existe.    APP_Activity_Sync   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets   1691

Tengo todos los archivos del API19 descargados con el SDK Manager.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A alguien le sucedio algo similar, cual es la solucion de este problema?

Comment: El mismo problema en:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36534094/what-is-packaged-resources Suerte!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solucion al error : Eliminar el Android SDK Build-tools del la carpeta Preview Channel.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi caso funciono correctamente y me dejo compilar el proyecto.